# How do I turn JavaScript off in Tor Browser Bundle 3.5?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, javascript

I've updated to the latest Tor Browser Bundle but the option to turn off JavaScript seems to have disappeared. What is the correct way to turn off JavaScript now? I tried to set `JavaScript enabled` to false in `about:config` but several sites still report JavaScript is active on my browser. How do I turn it off?

Comment: Click on the S! next to onion below Tor browser tab and then click on disable globally.

Comment: Navigate to: about:config .Then search for 'javascript' and set javascript.enabledto false.

Comment: Noscript options>advanced>Override Tor browsers level preset

Answer (score 7):

Do you have NoScript set to globally forbid all Javascript? NoScript in Tor Browser 3.5 seems to allow scripts by default, so you might want to check if it is overriding your Firefox settings. Click on the NoScript icon on the toolbar and select "Forbid scripts globally". You might also want to go to the "Options" (in the same menu) and edit the Whitelist section.

Answer (score 6):

Mozilla [removed option to disable JavaScript](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=873709) in Firefox version 23. Since 
Tor Browser 3.5+ series based on Firefox ESR 24, it shipped without this switch.

In addition to [Mike's answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/1069/731), you can also consult to [How do I disable JavaScript?](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowserBundle3FAQ#HowdoIdisableJavaScript) section on [Tor Browser Bundle 3 FAQ](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorBrowserBundle3FAQ).

Also, setting on `javascript.enabled` to false on `about:config` should actually disable JavaScript. Could you please check if your preference is stored correctly?

Also please note that there is a slight possibility that sites report your JavaScript as active could be simply wrong. You can test it on the following sites:

- [isjavascriptenabled.com](http://www.isjavascriptenabled.com/)
- [ipcheck.info](http://ipcheck.info)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Although we encourage you to cite links as part of an answer, it is good practise to summarise the content, or quote relevant excepts from the pgae, so that the answer can stand alone without the links working - this is useful if, for example, the webpage gets removed or changed.

Answer (score 2):

The actual Tor browser bundle has an option in the plugins window to activate the [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) plugin so you only need to restart the browser with that program.